# How do I plot data with an array that is weirdly shaped?

Tags: python

For some reason I don't understand, the array I'm using as the y value is not `(4500,)` shaped, but `(1125,)` with 4 values in each row. I can't figure out how to get it to work.

This is what I tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


wl = np.array(range(4500,9000))

der = np.empty(4500,)

with open('der.txt') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        np.append(der, line)


# plotting
# --------
x = wl
y = der

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

The .txt file looks like this:

```
[1.48088146e-38 1.59775424e-38 1.59922651e-38 1.60070013e-38
 1.60217510e-38 1.60365144e-38 1.49186765e-38 1.65874635e-38
 1.66096308e-38 1.66203429e-38 1.66310619e-38 1.66425542e-38
```

continuing for 1125 lines.

I'm helpful for any ideas, because I'm basically a total noob in coding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do here.  My advice if you are just getting started:  avoid `numpy` for now.  You can do almost anything with basic python data structures and you will find it a much easier onramp.

Comment: what does the file der.txt look like?

Comment: @JoKing As I guess from his question, the file contains 4 numbers per row, possibly separated by comma and 1125 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading your file wrong. Your file contains 4 numbers per row, so when you read it, you need to split them into individual numbers.

Assume the numbers are separated by comma in your file you can do:

```
# read the file, split each line
with open('der.txt', 'r') as fin:
     lines = fin.read().split("\n")

# get rid of empty lines and split each number, but still a nested list
# here assumes the delimiter is comma, if it's something else, just change
# it accordingly
lines = [l.split(",") for l in lines if l]

# flatten the list in to a single list
der = [float(item) for sublist in lines for item in sublist]
```

If you want to use numpy, you can do:

```
# read matrix
from numpy import genfromtxt
der_matrix = genfromtxt('der.txt', delimiter=',')

# conver to a long array
der = my_data.flatten()
```

Comment: Yes, I figured, I read the file wrong, but didn't know how to fix it. That makes a lot of sense now, thank you. I really enjoy learning new things here, the help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`np.append` involves array concatenation, which defeats the purpose of having the fixed-sized array `der`. I'm guessing that each line of `der` has 4 values in it, which is why when you do `np.append(der, line)` you only get 1125 lines. 
Try:

```
index = 0
with open('der.txt') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    for val in line.split():
        der[index] = val
        index += 1
```